# Unable to see the database created in Entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This may be basic question for entity frame work developers, would like to switch from as a database developer to Dot net developer.Started with basic sample with Entity framework model, but getting below exceptions while compiling.
Below is my main method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace EFMAin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
            {
    Student stud = new Student() { StudentName = "New Student" };

                ctx.Students.Add(stud);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below are my classes to create data base tables.

```
using ExampleCF.Models;
using ExampleCFA.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ExampleCF.Models
{
    public class Teacher
    {
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public string TeacherName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace ExampleCFA.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the Context class.
using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace EF_Code_First_Tutorials
{

    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext()
            : base()
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

    }
}
```

While compiling this application getting below exceptions.

> Error 3   'System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context' does not contain a
>   definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\EF\EFLab1Practice\EFCodeFirst\EFMAin\Program.cs  20  21  EFMAin
>
> Error 2   'System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Students' and no extension method 'Students' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\EF\EFLab1Practice\EFCodeFirst\EFMAin\Program.cs  19  21  EFMAin
>   Error 1   'System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context': type used in a
>   using statement must be implicitly convertible to
>   'System.IDisposable'  D:\EF\EFLab1Practice\EFCodeFirst\EFMAin\Program.cs  15  13  EFMAin

Anybody please suggest what would be the starting point for this.

I follwed [http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx][1]

as well as requesting you to suggest the best place to start entity framework.

Comment: Shouldn't `new Context()` be `new SchoolContext()`? You added `using ...` to have a `Context` class but it's the wrong one...

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: awesome, no errors now. thanks to stack overflow.based on this magic is in context class only , what it will do in high level?

Comment: `System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts.Context` and `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` are completely unrelated classes. _"what it will do in high level?"_. What do you mean?

Comment: one more issue is even I am able to compile the application, and there are no errors, but i am not able to see the database created.

Comment: `Student stud = new SchoolContext() { StudentName = "New Student" };` doesn't look good maybe you sould try this instead : `Student stud = new Student { StudentName = "New Student" };`

Comment: @ Emmanuel M: Modified it  but No errors, No database,No luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this turtorial My database was created in SQL Server = (localdb)\mssqllocaldb try to connect to this one and then check under databases

Comment: It was like that on my PC :-) and I did the same example from same webpage and spent alot of time to find the DB, hahaha